# Define how to store data in column on creation of table

Tags: oracle, postgresql, postgis

I am trying to port an Oracle database over to Postgres by editing scripts generated within Oracle and have come across some geometry type columns. I am using PostGIS in order to allow me to use geometry types and am adding the columns using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME
(
  ID           BIGINT                      NOT NULL,
  GEOM         GEOMETRY,
  CENTROID     GEOMETRY,
  R_CENTROID   GEOMETRY,
  NUM_POINTS   BIGINT,
  PK           BIGINT,
  EXTENT       GEOMETRY
);
```

This passes ok in the editor however the generated Oracle script specifies how to store the data in the geometry column as follows:

```
VARRAY "R_EXTENT"."SDO_ELEM_INFO" STORE AS LOB (
  ENABLE       STORAGE IN ROW
  CHUNK        8192
  RETENTION
  CACHE
  LOGGING
  INDEX       (
        STORAGE    (
                   INITIAL          64K
                    MINEXTENTS       1
                    MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                    PCTINCREASE      0
                    BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                   ))
        STORAGE    (
                   INITIAL          64K
                   MINEXTENTS       1
                   MAXEXTENTS       UNLIMITED
                   PCTINCREASE      0
                   BUFFER_POOL      DEFAULT
                   ))
```

This is just one column of course but how can this be achieved in postgres? Or more to the point can it be done full stop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can ignore the storage settings from the Oracle script. They only deal with the physical storage of the column values and don't influence the usage of the column at all.

PostgreSQL handles custom data types differently.

Just keep your original `CREATE TABLE` you don't need to change anything.